# Python Lambda Expression - Operations Between Returned List and Another List

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I have a lambda function which returns a list of options selected by the user against a question in the front-end. It looks like:

`selected_options = lambda x: get_options(x, question.id)`,

returning a list like `[5, 6]`. I want to check if any members of the returned list are in another list, say, `[2,5,7,11]`. Python wouldn't allow iterating on lambda expressions. Using `if selected_options in [2,5,7,11]` will check for whole returned list, not the individual members, so will work when user selects one options only.

If you can find a duplicate question, please point me to it. I couldn't.